# Switching wired interface in Server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, configuration

I have two 1 Gb wired Ethernet ports on a Dell server. I am trying to move to wired port #1 because of physical damage to wired port #2. The trouble is, 2008R2 won't let me have two interfaces with the same IP address. Ordinarily, I can see this being a good thing - it tries to save you from yourself. However, I am super-paranoid about changing the IP settings on port #1 - is there any way to have the interfaces configured identically so that I can revert the port change by just plugging the cable back into #1? Or, is there a way to save a wired interface config to a file?

It's a critical production server and I can't schedule maintenance on it much, so I didn't want to mess with currently working IP settings if I could help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `netsh` to dump the configuration of the production NIC:

```
netsh -c interface dump > path\dump-filename.txt
```

Then disable the damaged interface:

```
netsh interface set interface interface-name DISABLED
```

Then, on the other interface:

```
netsh -f path\dump-filename.txt
```

Comment: This was great advice! I took a backup of the interface configs as you wrote here, but  then I disabled #1 and configured #2 with identical settings and it worked out.

Comment: @user65712 Consider removing the settings from the disabled interface now, because if it ever gets re-enabled, it will conflict with the other port and cause all sorts of havoc.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you are just going to have to schedule maintenance. There's no way to do that without a maintenance window.

Could you assign another IP to the second interface and use DNS migrate to the other?